# Best way to reuse JavaScript for common html elements

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form that takes in values from a dropdown list. When an option is selected the HTML badge is updated to display the status of Good or Bad.

Each badge element span class is the same, but the ID is different as I need to capture the result.

Is there a way that I can use a single JavaScript function against all span classes but only update the span class for where the dropdown box is?

Or do I need to define every element ID within the JavaScript function.

The `<span class="badge badge-soft-success"` is on every badge.

```js
const changeBadgeColour = document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level');

changeBadgeColour.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var p_status = document.getElementById("project-tier-entry-level");
  p_status_value = p_status.options[p_status.selectedIndex].value;


  const statusBadge = document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level-status');
  if (p_status_value === "Yes") {

    document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level-status').className = 'badge badge-soft-success'
    document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level-status').textContent = 'Good!'

  } else {
    document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level-status').className = 'badge badge-soft-danger'
    document.getElementById('project-tier-entry-level-status').textContent = 'Bad!'
  }

  console.log()

});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label class="form-label" for="project-tier-entry-level-label">Does the project land in our Tiered entry levels?</label>
  <span class="badge badge-soft-success" id="project-tier-entry-level-status"></span>
  <select class="form-control" name="choices-single-no-sorting" id="project-tier-entry-level">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
    <option>Yes</option>
    <option>No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `this.closest('div').querySelector('span.badge')` to get from the <select>'s event handler to the badge span in the same div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "SELECT" && tgt.id.startsWith("project-tier")) { // in case there are other things that can change in that container
    const yes = tgt.value === "Yes"
    const statusBadge = tgt.previousElementSibling; // or tgt.closest('div').querySelector('span.badge');
    statusBadge.classList.toggle("badge-soft-success", yes)
    statusBadge.classList.toggle("badge-soft-danger", !yes)
    statusBadge.textContent = yes ? 'Good!' : 'Bad!';
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-label" for="project-tier-entry-level-label">Does the project land in our Tiered entry levels?</label>
    <span class="badge badge-soft-success" id="project-tier-entry-level-status"></span>
    <select class="form-control" name="choices-single-no-sorting" id="project-tier-entry-level">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-label" for="project-tier-entry-level-label">Does the project land in our Tiered normal levels?</label>
    <span class="badge badge-soft-success" id="project-tier-normal-level-status"></span>
    <select class="form-control" name="choices-single-no-sorting" id="project-tier-normal-level">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Three options with a result of the selections:

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "SELECT" && tgt.id.startsWith("project-tier")) { // in case there are other things that can change in that container
    const badge = tgt.value
    const statusBadge = tgt.previousElementSibling; // or tgt.closest('div').querySelector('span.badge');
    statusBadge.classList.toggle("badge-soft-success", badge==="Yes")
    statusBadge.classList.toggle("badge-soft-danger",  badge==="No")
    statusBadge.classList.toggle("badge-soft-unknown",  badge==="Unknown")
    const text = {"Yes":"Good!","No":"Bad!","Unknown":"Unknown!"}[badge] || "What?"
    statusBadge.textContent = text;
    
    const res =  [...document.querySelectorAll("#container select[id^=project-tier]")]
      .reduce((acc, sel) => {
        if (acc[sel.value] != undefined) acc[sel.value]++;
        else acc["Not set"]++;
        return acc
      },{"Yes":0,"No":0,"Unknown":0,"Not set":0})
    document.getElementById("result").value = Object.entries(res).map(([key,val]) => `${key}: ${val}`).join('\n')
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="tierForm">
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-label" for="project-tier-entry-level-label">Does the project land in our Tiered entry levels?</label>
    <span class="badge badge-soft-success" id="project-tier-entry-level-status"></span>
    <select class="form-control" name="choices-single-no-sorting" id="project-tier-entry-level">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Unknown</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label class="form-label" for="project-tier-entry-level-label">Does the project land in our Tiered normal levels?</label>
    <span class="badge badge-soft-success" id="project-tier-normal-level-status"></span>
    <select class="form-control" name="choices-single-no-sorting" id="project-tier-normal-level">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Unknown</option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<textarea readonly id="result"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: How would I add on a 3rd option, to this solution? Like Yes, No, Unknown?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife See update

Comment: Amazing. Thank you mplungjan. This may be best as a separate question, but is it possible to calculate how many Yes, No, Unknows have been selected and update a field in the form. Like total yes 5

Comment: @JacksWastedLife See update

Comment: Awesome, you sure know your JS. :) And this is the very last question. How can i split the results so that yes goes to one field, no to another and unknown to another, I can't work out how to split the key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

How about if you assign the class name directly to your `changeBadgeColour` variable with querySelectorAll.

```
const changeBadgeColour = document.querySelectorAll('.badge .badge-soft-success')
```

Comment: yes typo thanks  @Liam